# Is there a faster method for making paired comparisons than expand.grid in Base R?

Tags: r, performance, optimization, vectorization

Colleagues,

I want to estimate the likelihood that a randomly-selected item from one group will have a higher score than a randomly-selected item from a different group. That is the *Probability of Superiority*, sometimes called the *Common-language Effect Size* See for example: https://rpsychologist.com/d3/cohend/. This can be resolved algebraically if we accept that the data are normally distributed [(McGraw and Wong (1992, Psychological Bulletin, 111)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1037/0033-2909.111.2.361) but I know that my data are not normally distributed, making such an estimate unreliable.

My solution is simple brute force. Using sample data, we compare each observation in one group with each observation in the other group, counting frequency where a>b and halving any ties.

My first attempt was a *For If Else* loop, and looked like this:

```
# Generate sample data
alpha <- as.integer(runif(2000, min = 0, max = 100))
beta <- as.integer(runif(2000, min = 0, max = 100))
nPairs <- length(alpha) * length(beta)

#initialise vars
bigger  <- 0
equal   <- 0.0
smaller <- 0

# Loop
for (i in alpha) {
  for (j in beta) {
    if (i > j) {bigger <- bigger + 1}
    else
      if (i < j) {smaller <- smaller + 1}
    else
    {equal <- equal + 0.5}
  }
}

# record Probability a > b
PaGTb <- (bigger + equal) / nPairs
```

This does the job, but it's woefully slow, especially in a **Shiny** app.

A work colleague reminded me that ***R*** is vector based, and suggested the `expand.grid` function. So my second attempt looks like this:

```
# generating sample data
alpha <- as.integer(runif(2000, min = 0, max = 100))
beta <- as.integer(runif(2000, min = 0, max = 100))
nPairs <- length(alpha) * length(beta)

# Each observation in alpha is paired with each observation in beta
c <- expand.grid(a = alpha, b = beta)

# Count frequency of a > b
aGTb <- length(which(c$a > c$b))
aEQb <- length(which(c$a == c$b))
aGTb <- aGTb + (0.5 * aEQb)

# record Probability a > b
PaGTb <- aGTb / nPairs
```

The speed is noticeably faster!

But not a quantum step faster. With simulations, I found that the vector-based method is faster for many paired comparisons (millions), but the For-If-Else method is faster for relatively few comparisons (thousands). The following table summarises results for 1000 replications of 3334*3000=10,002,000 paired comparisons on my iMac.

```
     time_ForIfElse    time_Vector     Ratio_Vector/ForIfElse
     Min.   :0.3514   Min.   :0.2835   Min.   :0.2713  
     1st Qu.:0.3648   1st Qu.:0.2959   1st Qu.:0.7818  
     Median :0.3785   Median :0.3102   Median :0.8115  
     Mean   :0.4037   Mean   :0.3322   Mean   :0.8309  
     3rd Qu.:0.4419   3rd Qu.:0.3678   3rd Qu.:0.8668  
     Max.   :1.4124   Max.   :0.5896   Max.   :1.4726
```

So, for the kind of data I'm working with, the vector-based method is about 20% faster than my original approach. But I'm still thinking that there may be a faster way of dealing with this problem.

Any thoughts from the community?

Comment: The vectorized method looks pretty good to me, if you want to compare all possible pairs. But do you actually need to do that? Could you just sample say 10,000 pairs? That would allow you to keep the time low, even when the dataset gets larger.

Comment: No, I guess I don't need to use all of the data. Sampling does work pretty well, as I did in [this Shiny app](https://winzar.shinyapps.io/PISA_Antecedents/). In that case there really are many millions of comparisons, so felt forced to use that tactic. Thank you for the suggestion, Marius. I feel much more confident with my choices now, even if my coding still sucks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a complete base solution that relies on `table()` and is inspired by @chinsoon12.

```
f_int_AUC <- function(a, b){
  A <- table(a)
  A_Freq = as.vector(A)
  A_alpha = as.integer(names(A))

  B <- table(b)
  B_Freq = as.vector(B)
  B_beta = as.integer(names(B))

  bigger = 0
  equal = 0

  for (i in seq_along(A_alpha)){
    bigger = bigger + sum(A_Freq[i] * B_Freq[A_alpha[i] > B_beta])
    equal = equal + 0.5 * sum(A_Freq[i] * B_Freq[A_alpha[i] == B_beta])
  }

  (bigger + equal) / (length(a) * length(b))
}
```

It's important to use this as a function - it is around 8 times faster on 4,000 rows than an uncompiled loop.

```
Unit: milliseconds
              expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
   base_int_AUC_fx 1.0187 1.03865 1.146774 1.10930 1.13230  5.3215   100
      base_int_AUC 8.3071 8.43380 9.309865 8.53855 8.88005 40.3327   100
```

Profiling of the function showed that the `table()` call was slowing this solution down. To address it, `tabulate()` is incorporated now for significant speed gains. The downside of `tabulate()` is that it doesn't name its bins. Therefore, we need to normalize the bins (h/t to @chinsoon12 for an additional 20% improvement):

```
f_int_AUC2 <- function(a,b) {
# tabulate does not include 0, therefore we need to
# normalize to positive integers.
  m <- min(c(a,b))

  A_Freq = tabulate(a - min(m) + 1)
  B_Freq = tabulate(b - min(m) + 1)

# calculate the outer product.  
  out_matrix <- outer(A_Freq, B_Freq)
  bigger = sum(out_matrix[lower.tri(out_matrix)])

  equal = 0.5 * sum(diag(out_matrix))

  (bigger + equal) / length(a) / length(b)
}
```

One thing to note that using `table()` or `tabulate()` makes assumption and would not work well on floating point numbers. Based on @Aaron's suggestion, I looked at the `wilcox.text` code and made a few simplifications based on the question. Note I extracted the code from the function - the `wilcox.test()` function is 437 lines of code - this is only 4 lines of it which provides significant speed increases.

```
f_wilcox_AUC <- function(a, b){
  # r <- data.table::frank(c(a, b)) #is much faster
  r <- rank(c(a, b))

  n.x <- as.integer(length(a))
  n.y <- as.integer(length(b))

# from wilcox.test STATISTIC; I am not a statistician and do not follow
# see reference at end or Google "r wilcox.test code"
  {sum(r[seq_along(a)]) - n.x * (n.x + 1) / 2} / n.x / n.y
}
```

**Performance:**

4,000 x 4,000

```
Unit: microseconds
           expr   min    lq  mean median    uq   max neval
 bigstats_prive   719   748   792    797   817   884    10
    chinsoon_DT  5910  6050  6280   6210  6350  7180    10
   base_int_AUC  1060  1070  2660   1130  1290 16300    10
  base_int_AUC2   237   250  1430    256   266 12000    10
    wilcox_base  1050  1050  1830   1060  1070  8790    10
      wilcox_dt   500   524  2940    530   603 16800    10
    wilcox_test 11300 11400 11900  11500 11700 13400    10
```

40,000 x 40,000

```
Unit: milliseconds
           expr    min     lq   mean median     uq    max neval
 bigstats_prive   4.03   4.07   5.13   4.11   4.27  66.40   100
    chinsoon_DT   6.62   7.01   7.88   7.44   7.75  19.20   100
   base_int_AUC   4.53   4.60   5.96   4.68   4.81  93.40   100
  base_int_AUC2   1.03   1.07   1.14   1.08   1.12   3.70   100
    wilcox_base  13.70  13.80  14.10  13.80  14.00  26.50   100
      wilcox_dt   1.87   2.00   2.38   2.11   2.23   6.25   100
    wilcox_test 115.00 118.00 121.00 121.00 124.00 135.00   100
```

400,000 x 400,000

```
Unit: milliseconds
           expr    min     lq   mean median     uq    max neval
 bigstats_prive   50.3   54.0   55.0   54.7   56.8   58.6    10
    chinsoon_DT   19.8   20.9   22.6   22.7   23.7   27.3    10
   base_int_AUC   43.6   45.3   53.3   47.8   49.6  108.0    10
  base_int_AUC2   10.0   10.4   11.8   10.7   13.8   14.8    10
    wilcox_base  252.0  254.0  271.0  258.0  293.0  316.0    10
      wilcox_dt   19.4   20.8   22.1   22.6   23.6   24.2    10
    wilcox_test 1440.0 1460.0 1480.0 1480.0 1500.0 1520.0    10
```

In all, using the base function will take 210 ms to do 1,000 replications of 4,000 X 4,000 comparisons:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 13
  expression          min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result    memory             time     gc                  
  <bch:expr>     <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>    <list>             <list>   <list>              
1 bigstats_prive  680.9us  692.8us    1425.   410.76KB     8.60   994     6   697.45ms <dbl [1]> <df[,3] [12 x 3]>  <bch:tm> <tibble [1,000 x 3]>
2 chinsoon_DT      5.55ms   6.02ms     166.   539.92KB     4.78   972    28      5.85s <dbl [1]> <df[,3] [82 x 3]>  <bch:tm> <tibble [1,000 x 3]>
3 base_int_AUC    981.8us   1.02ms     958.   750.44KB    10.7    989    11      1.03s <dbl [1]> <df[,3] [606 x 3]> <bch:tm> <tibble [1,000 x 3]>
4 base_int_AUC2   203.7us  209.3us    4743.   454.36KB    33.4    993     7   209.38ms <dbl [1]> <df[,3] [22 x 3]>  <bch:tm> <tibble [1,000 x 3]>
5 wilcox_base      1.03ms   1.04ms     959.   359.91KB     4.82   995     5      1.04s <dbl [1]> <df[,3] [11 x 3]>  <bch:tm> <tibble [1,000 x 3]>
6 wilcox_dt       410.4us  444.5us    2216.   189.09KB     6.67   997     3   450.01ms <dbl [1]> <df[,3] [9 x 3]>   <bch:tm> <tibble [1,000 x 3]>
7 wilcox_test     11.35ms  11.44ms      85.6    1.16MB     1.66   981    19     11.45s <dbl [1]> <df[,3] [58 x 3]>  <bch:tm> <tibble [1,000 x 3]>
```

**edit:** see previous methods for inefficient methods using `outer()` and `data.table::CJ()`

**References**:
https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/stats/R/wilcox.test.R

Comment: Thank you, @cole. This is extraordinary. Much appreciated.

Comment: just a suggestion to remove `rng` and use  `A_Freq = tabulate(a-min(a)+1); B_Freq = tabulate(b-min(b)+1)`. cant upvote twice though

Comment: @chinsoon12, I included that and also made changes to the lengths of the vectors. Is about 20% faster than the previous ```tabulate()``` version. Great suggestion

Comment: just a feedback, is the lengthen part really required? `f <- function(a, b) {
    m <- min(c(a,b));
    x <- tabulate(a-m+1);
    y <- tabulate(b-m+1);
    A <- outer(x,y);
    (sum(A[lower.tri(A)]) + 0.5*sum(diag(A))) / length(a) / length(b)
}` then manually checking with 2 cases of unequal length vectors seems ok e.g. `f(c(2,3,4,5,9), c(1,5,10))` and `f(c(1,5,10), c(2,3,4,5,9))`

Comment: @chinsoon12 I didn't realize that ```lower.tri``` could take non-square matrices so I wanted your ```x``` and ```y``` vectors to be of equal length. Your way is better and while I was testing, I see your addition of ```m <- min(c(a,b))``` fixes some other issues with my function. Thank you for the follow-up - editing now.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. Sorry for the multiple comments

Comment: Thanks for your considered contribution, @Cole. Your link to the original code helped me to understand what was going on, but also showed me (again) that we don't have to accept the default all the time. It's been 30 years since I studied matrix algebra... I have much to catch up on.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you want to compute something similar to the Area Under the ROC Curve (AUC).

A very fast way to achieve this is to use:

```
bigstatsr::AUC(c(alpha, beta), rep(1:0, c(length(alpha), length(beta))))
```

(Disclaimer: I'm the author of {bigstatsr})

Comment: Quadruple Wow!
Thank you, @F. Privé.
Your AUC function reduces the run-time by a factor of 6.
Previous median speed was about 107 milliseconds for 10K pairs.
Your UAC gives median speed about 0.000082 milliseconds.
I have so much more work to do...

Comment: Try with larger data and you'll get even more increase :')

Comment: @F.Prive - see edit on my post as the performance is interesting. Also, I already +1 yours but when I was trying to squeeze out performance, my first attempt in ```Rcpp``` was what you had commented out in your ```bigstatsr``` package. Your sorted algorithm is amazing.

Comment: @Cole I see. Your solution makes use of that alpha and beta are integers in a finite range. I can't have this expectation in my package.

Answer (score 3):

This is what the Wilcoxon test tests for; the test statistic there is simply the count of how many pairs for which one is bigger, so to get the proportion simply divide.

```
wilcox.test(alpha, beta)$statistic / (length(alpha)*length(beta))
```

This might need to be adjusted for ties; I'd have to review the details.

Comment: That works. It's slower than the other answers but it's pretty generalized - floating point vectors would be good to go.

Comment: Agreed, it works nicely, @Aaron. Slower, but easily explained.

Comment: Yes, it is usually possible to write faster code than base R, especially if you don't generalize it. But it somehow still surprises me when people reinvent the wheel without first testing whether or not the existing wheel is fast enough...

Comment: As it turns out, the wilcox.test is a lot faster than all but the AUC function from @fprive.

Comment: The non-statisticians in R do not know the wheel exist. Regarding performance, the ```wilcox.test``` only shines when its method for area under the curve is extracted. It's around 10 times faster when just the ```$statistic``` is calculated compared to all the other outputs. Still, thank you for pointing out the ```wilcox.test``` - I learned a lot.

Comment: Yes, if you run into grumpy statisticians (sorry about that...) it's because too often data scientists think they've come up with something cool (and usually it is something cool!) but it's something we've known for a long time, and have already worked out the issues involved, which the data scientist may not have even discovered yet. Part of the fault is ours for being "boring" for so long, but to give the past the benefit of the doubt, before computers existed, it must have been hard not to be boring! But now when (many) data science programs minimize our hard-won knowledge it's a shame.

Comment: As far as the speed goes, the built-in functions are slower for important reasons: they contain error-checking code and code for special cases. In this case almost all the slowdown is from dealing with potential ties. If you really need the speed and can guarantee that your input is appropriate and that you don't need the special cases, then by all means go for it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option using `data.table` to aggregate first before performing a non-equi join and counting occurrences:

```
DTa <- data.table(a=alpha)[, .N, keyby=a]
DTb <- data.table(b=beta)[, .N, keyby=b]
(DTb[DTa, on=.(b<a), allow.cartesian=TRUE, nomatch=0L, sum(N*i.N)] + 
        0.5 * DTb[DTa, on=.(b=a), allow.cartesian=TRUE, nomatch=0L, sum(N*i.N)]) / nPairs
```

timing code:

```
mtd0 <- function() {
    c <- expand.grid(a = alpha, b = beta)
    aGTb <- length(which(c$a > c$b))
    aEQb <- length(which(c$a == c$b))
    aGTb <- aGTb + (0.5 * aEQb)
    aGTb / nPairs
}

mtd1 <- function() {
    CJ(a = alpha, b = beta, sorted=FALSE)[, {
        aGTb = sum(a > b)
        aEQb = sum(a == b)
        aGTb = aGTb + 0.5 * aEQb
        PaGTb = aGTb / nPairs 
    }]
}

mtd2 <- function() {
    DTa <- data.table(a=alpha)[, .N, keyby=a]
    DTb <- data.table(b=beta)[, .N, keyby=b]
    (DTb[DTa, on=.(b<a), allow.cartesian=TRUE, nomatch=0L, sum(N*i.N)] + 
            0.5 * DTb[DTa, on=.(b=a), allow.cartesian=TRUE, nomatch=0L, sum(N*i.N)]) / nPairs
}

bench::mark(mtd0(), mtd1(), mtd2())
```

timings:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 14
  expression      min     mean   median      max `itr/sec` mem_alloc  n_gc n_itr total_time result    memory              time     gc                
  <chr>      <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt> <dbl> <int>   <bch:tm> <list>    <list>              <list>   <list>            
1 mtd0()     589.55ms 589.55ms 589.55ms    590ms      1.70     580MB     3     1      590ms <dbl [1]> <Rprofmem [20 x 3]> <bch:tm> <tibble [1 x 3]>  
2 mtd1()     188.01ms 228.04ms 192.55ms    304ms      4.39     244MB     5     3      684ms <dbl [1]> <Rprofmem [15 x 3]> <bch:tm> <tibble [3 x 3]>  
3 mtd2()       4.14ms   4.82ms   4.52ms     23ms    208.       541KB     1   104      501ms <dbl [1]> <Rprofmem [84 x 3]> <bch:tm> <tibble [104 x 3]>
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(0L)
nr <- 4e3
alpha <- as.integer(runif(nr, min = 0, max = 100))
beta <- as.integer(runif(nr, min = 0, max = 100))
nPairs <- length(alpha) * length(beta)
```

Comment: Thank you for walking me through those three options, @chinsoon12. All base R, and I can understand what’s going on.